# SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2 can't find my local server ~ what's wrong?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2016

I have just installed SQL Server 2016 CTP3.2 on a Windows 10 machine.

The problem I have now is that SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is not able to find the local server.

The Database Engine has not any server and if I click "" only the Integration Services has identified the local server (the computer name).

Why can´t the database engine locate the local server?

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep, are you still running into this problem? To view the local database server, you can type in "." under the server name input.